# Is UWP/Xamarin ready for enterprise applications?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, crm, enterprise

Is UWP or Xamarin is usable for enterprise applications like CRM, ERP, etc...
Is the any sample on market, or there are any patterns?

These platform are firstly mobile platforms, but they had a excellent support, a lot of graphically possibility and very modern look and feel. These platform are designed for mobile application in first line, but they are ready for enterprice applications?

Of course the are lot of extension in built control (DataGrid, Charts) which makes possible to create enterprise application. But I did not find any. Is there and problem or drawback of this platforms?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is UWP/Xamarin ready for enterprise applications?

The answer is yes. Xamarin UWP applies not only to mobile platforms but also to desktop platforms(Windows 10). You could also run it in the desktop client. This benefits from the [native universal window platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide).

For pattern, there many pattern you could select such as  `publish-subscribe` `MVVM` etc. For more you could refer [**Enterprise Application Patterns using Xamarin.Forms**](http://aka.ms/XamarinPatternsEbook).

For enterprise publish, you could think of Xamarin UWP application as UWP application, and [**Distribute LOB apps to enterprises**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/distribute-lob-apps-to-enterprises) document has described the details of publish process.

And this [blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/developing-enterprise-apps-using-xamarin-forms/) describe the possibility of Xamarin.Form enterprise application that you could refer.

Comment: Thank You! This is what I want!

Comment: If the answer has resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later, Thanks for understanding.